# SharedPreference does not run on my flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to save user preferences using Flutter's SharedPreference. But the registered preferences are ALL null at newstart (cannot save session if I start my apps) my sharedpreference not work in my flutter project.

My code:

```
var value;
getProf() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    value = prefs.getInt('value');


    _loginStatus = value == 1 ? LoginStatus.signIn : LoginStatus.notSignIn;
  });
}

login() async {
  final response = await http.post(
      "https://smartnote12.000webhostapp.com/login/api/login.php",
      body: {"username": username, "password": password});
  final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  int value = data['value'];
  String pesan = data['message'];
  if (value == 1) {
    setState(() {
      _loginStatus = LoginStatus.signIn;

      print(pesan);
    });
  } else {
    _showAlert(context);
  }
}

void _showAlert(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Login"),
            content: Text("Password & Username Salah"),
          ));
}
```

In here I call function state but it's not working

```
@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  getProf();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  switch (_loginStatus) {
    case LoginStatus.notSignIn:
      return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Container(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't call getProf() in initState(). you can use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 new FutureBuilder<LoginStatus>(
    future: getProf(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<LoginStatus> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Loading');
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            loginStatus = snapshot.data;
            if(loginStatus.notSignIn) {
             // login button is here
             return Container(child: Text('not signed in'));
            }
            else {
             return Container(child: Text('Signed in'));
            }
          } else {
           return  Container(child: Text('error'));
          }
      }
    },
  )
 }
```

Comment: login it's okay but cannot save session

Comment: save value in login function 
`if (value == 1) {
    setState(() {
      _loginStatus = LoginStatus.signIn;

      //here you must save value...
      prefs.setInt(key,value);

      print(pesan);
    });
  }`